# Golang Postgres How To Dump Tables Into JSON

Tags: postgresql, go

I'm trying to run this command for many tables (one table at a time) in Go 1.9:

```
COPY (select row_to_json(foo) FROM (SELECT * FROM bar) foo ) TO '/tmp/bar.json';
```

Is this even possible? It seems with lib/pg, it is not. With go-pg, I keep running out of memory because it buffers it all into memory first.

Doing this from the command prompt works fine. I'd rather use Go's PG libs than have it run it at command prompt.

In short, I'm trying to dump entire tables into JSON in their own files.

Has anyone done this successfully?

Thank you!

EDIT:

Since lb/pg didn't support this at all, I'm using pg-go. Here is the code:

```
var buf bytes.Buffer
    _, err := db.CopyTo(&buf, "COPY (select row_to_json(foo) FROM (SELECT * FROM bar) r ) TO '/tmp/bar.json'")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
```

Comment: It seems that `COPY TO` isn't supported yet in `lib/pq` and `jackc/pgx`. How did you execute `COPY TO` in `go-pg` (query and code snippet) that causing *out of memory*? Looking at the source code of `go-pg`, it reads then write the data in chunk (no *buffers it all into memory first*).

Comment: Have you tried: `\copy (SELECT json_agg(foo) FROM foo) TO '/tmp/foo.json'` Posgres **>9.20** required.

Comment: Sorry for my english but, why are you just dont ``select row_to_json(foo) FROM (SELECT * FROM bar) foo`` writing result into file?

Comment: Updated my question with the code.

Comment: In response to nk2ge5k: because that would use up too much RAM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two approaches to export table(s) into json file using `COPY`.

1. Using [go-pg](https://github.com/go-pg/pg). To avoid *out of memory* issue, instead of writing the result to buffer, the result should be written  directly to a file. The snippets will be:

   ```
   //open database connection first
   db := pg.Connect(&pg.Options{
       User:     "username",
       Password: "password",
       Database: "database",
       Addr:     "192.168.1.2:5432",   //database address
   })
   defer db.Close()

   //open output file
   out, err := os.Create("/tmp/bar.json")
   if err != nil {
       panic(err)
   }
   defer out.Close()

   //execute opy
   copy := `COPY (SELECT row_to_json(foo) FROM (SELECT * FROM bar) foo ) TO STDOUT`
   _, err = db.CopyTo(out, copy)
   if err != nil {
       panic(err)
   }
   ```
2. Using [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html) and [exec](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/) package. Basically, this approach execute a `psql` command in the form of: `psql -c query1 -c query2 ... args`. Please note, this approach requires that `psql` is already installed. The snippets:

   ```
   queries := []string{
       `SET client_encoding='UTF8'`,
       `\COPY (SELECT row_to_json(foo) FROM (SELECT * FROM bar) foo ) TO '/tmp/bar.json'`,
   }
   dsn := "postgresql://username:password@192.168.1.2/database"

   //construct arguments
   args := []string{}
   for _, q := range queries {
       args = append(args, "-c", q)
   }
   args = append(args, dsn)

   //Execute psql command
   cmd := exec.Command("psql", args...)
   stdoutStderr, err := cmd.CombinedOutput()
   if err != nil {
       panic(err)
   }
   fmt.Printf("%s\n", stdoutStderr)
   ```

### Note

Adjust the value of connection parameters (`username`, `password`, `host/ip address`, etc) as needed. For the detail, please refer to [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-connect.html#libpq-connstring).